# "All there is is light" - repeating the word "is"

Tags: sentence, repetition

The sentence in question:

*All there is is light.*

The sentence appears in a context of a novel, where a great flash of light is described. *"All there is..."* is meant to describe the fact that the "light" has replaced all other things in the world. This sentence is also in a single paragraph populated by itself alone, and this is meant to create an impressive effect.

The structure of the sentence necessitates the immediate repetition of the word "is" which seems to be grammatically disputable.

I am asking to see if there is any rule that explicitly mark this sentence as incorrect, or if there is any alternative to the sentence that is similarly succinct.

Comment: It's a perfectly legitimate sentence, though, as you might suppose, the pattern can cause your tongue to trip and stumble at times.

Comment: *All there is* is the subject.

Comment: Is that all there is?

Comment: You can say "Is that all that is?" and make a palindrome.

Comment: That that *is* is causing you concern tells me that you’re not parsing it correctly: “all there is” is a noun phrase.

Comment: Yes, it's an NP containing a subordinate content clause, "there is" : "[All (that) there is] is light". (the NP is bracketed, "that" is optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *All there is is light.*

This sentence is not in any way ungrammatical. Just because there are two consecutive *is*'s does not necessarily mean the sentence is ungrammatical.

On the contrary, if you take out one of the *is*'s from that sentence, the lack of another *is* makes it ungrammatical:

> *All there is light.* (??)

If you'd like a simpler structure, you might say instead:

> *There is only light.*

So the OP's sentence is a cleft construction of sorts in the sense that you have divided the single information into two pieces, which requires two finite verbs. A more legit cleft would be something like this:

> It is only light that there is.

Also, there's some other similar constructions available:

> *The only thing there is is light.*
>
> *What there is is only light.*